Reset settings when the screen is broken
My device runs on my own android build based on LineageOS 19.1
Not so long ago, I accidentally turned on an experimental feature for my phone and the entire screen went blank.
When turned on, the system flashes for one second and the screen turns off.
I need to copy my files from my phone or disable the feature in the settings.

The touchscreen is working.
The bootloader is unlocked.

But all my data is encrypted, and the phone rejects all USB, while the system is running. Everything works in the bootloader and recovery.

I tried to use TWRP, but it can't decrypt the data after Android 8.
I also tried to use USB debugging, but it doesn't work without disabling the USB restriction.


Does the phone have a lock screen? If yes which type? For enabling adb you could try to modify the system partition. This should work as only the user data is encrypted. https://xdaforums.com/t/lineageos-how-to-enable-adb-via-twrp-recovery.4636665/post-89109547

Yes, It does. a PIN code.

So you could enter it using an usb keyboard. Afterwards the user data files would be accessible (decrypted). If you would manage to enable adb by default you had full access then.

Does not work. The terminal writes "adb: inaccessible or not found"

Have you modified your system Android system as shown in the xda post? A similar approach was shown some posts below by alecxs: https://xdaforums.com/t/lineageos-how-to-enable-adb-via-twrp-recovery.4636665/post-89110290

I can't do this. Android does not decrypt the system.

The system partition is never encrypted. Thus Android doesn't has to decrypt anything if you want to modify it. On normal devices modifying the system partition is prevented by the locked bootloader and the vbmeta signatures from Android Verified Boot, but as you are running LineageOS both shouldn't be a problem.
